# create dataframe from specific node in json response

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 12121,
      "product": "hair",
      "tag":"now, later",
      "types": [
        {
          "product_id": 11111,
          "id": 22222
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1313131,
        "product": "pillow",
        "tag":"later, never",
        "types": [
          {
            "product_id": 33333,
            "id": 44444
          }
        ],
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "Title"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 14141414,
        "product": "face",
        "tag":"now, never",
        "types": [
          {
            "product_id": 5555,
            "id": 7777
          }
        ],
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "Title"
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking to create a dataframe of the values found in `types` only when the `tag` list says "now", output expected:

```
    tag   product_id  id
0   now   11111       22222     
1   now   5555        7777
```

I was hoping for some guidance as I haven't dealt with JSON structures that have multiples lists and how to target based on finding a value like what is inside `tag`. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a list comprehension:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([{'tag': 'now', **i['types'][0]} for i in dct['products'] if 'now' in i['tag']])
   tag  product_id     id
0  now       11111  22222
1  now        5555   7777
>>>
```